# Why do ASP.Net server control declarations require the runat="server" attribute?

Tags: asp.net, compiler-construction, servercontrols, runatserver

Surely the fact that they're declared beginning with "<asp:" is enough to infer they're server controls?  Or is it just included for completeness (so they look similar to the server control declaration of <input runat="server" for example).  Or is there some special reason?

It just always bugs me that the compiler tells me I've missed it off when I do so accidentally.  Kind of like the thinking behind "var" - if the compiler knows what it is.. why bother expecting me to state it?

Comment: Check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304290/asp-net-why-runatserver

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from [this forum thread](http://forums.asp.net/p/767126/767612.aspx):

> Internet Explorer supports DHTML
>   behaviors.
>
> [The asp:control syntax] does not mean server
>   control. You can create client DHTML
>   component that has namespace and will
>   run on the client machine. Also,
>   namespaces are allowed in XHTML and
>   techically you can use asp namespace
>   for something else on a client, if you
>   wish. Runat="server" prevents
>   namespace clash. If element has no
>   runat="server" attribute, it will be
>   sent to the client browser unchanged.
>   Therefore, you can use HTML components
>   (HTCs) in ASP.NET pages as well.
>
> Have a look here
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/author/behaviors/howto/creating.asp
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/author/behaviors/overview.asp

Mike Schinkel also [has a blog post](http://mikeschinkel.com/blog/whyrunatserverforaspnetpart2/) exploring why runat=server is necessary.

Comment: I would have closed my question as a duplicate (also see below) but it wont let me.  Any ideas?