# How do I reference the input of an HTML <textarea> control in codebehind?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm using a textarea control to allow the user to input text and then place that text into the body of an e-mail. In the code behind, what is the syntax for referencing the users input? I thought I could just use `message.Body = test123.Text;` but this is not recognized.

HTML:

```html
<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2" ></textarea>
```

CodeBehind:

```c#
foreach (string recipient in recipients)
{         
  var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("sender@example.com", recipient);
  message.Subject = "Hello World!";         
  message.Body = test123.Text;                
  client.Send(message); 
}
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You are not using a .NET control for your text area. Either add `runat="server"` to the HTML TextArea control or use a .NET control:

Try this:

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" />
```

Then reference it in your codebehind:

```
message.Body = TextArea1.Text;
```

Comment: tentonipete has the best answer for me, but I would add the Columns and Rows attribute. For example, Columns="40" Rows="5".

Answer (score 19):

You need to use `runat="server"` like this:

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2" runat="server"></textarea>
```

You can use the runat=server attribute with any standard HTML element, and later use it from codebehind.

Answer (score 10):

First make sure you have the `runat="server"` attribute in your `textarea` tag like this

```
<textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2" runat="server"></textarea>
```

Then you can access the content via:

```
string body = TextArea1.value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the textarea ID and include the [`runat="server"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304290/asp-net-why-runat-server) attribute to the [`textarea`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp)

```
message.Body = TextArea1.Text;
```

What is `test123`?

---

Comment: this still wouldn't work as runat="server" is not on the html control

Answer (score 0):

Missed property `runat="server"` or in code use `Request.Params["TextArea1"]`