# how to display multiline text retrived from db

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

How to display retrieved text from database into multiline **not** single *horizontal*  line in
 asp.net web project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For edit form use [textarea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) html tag. Also you can use [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editors(for example [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)).
For view you can use any tag for display multiline text.

Comment: more explaination please !!

Comment: can I limit the number of lines ?

Comment: If you put your text on a p tag, for example, the browser will wrap the text into multiple lines, but on a web page line breaks does not break lines...

Comment: You have to use <br/> tag to insert break line, on your page

Comment: no I can't ! because all text are retrieved from database ... then I put the text into a label

Comment: Before you print page, you can replace all line breaks with <br/> tags, use regex, it is very effective

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076466/javascript-replace-n-with-br

Comment: Hmm the problem is : I retrieve this text into a Label ... so I can't manipulate it ... but this way I'll try to retrieve it in a different way

Comment: `  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("subject") %>'></asp:Label>                                   `

and this is the code behind : ` articlesDL.DataSource = DS.select_all_articles();
        articlesDL.DataBind();`

Comment: Actually, an asp:label is rendered as a span tag, you can manipulate you text before set it into your label text

Comment: Can you use textbox with multiline like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508051/textarea-control-asp-net-c-sharp?

Comment: @test1604 it won't be nice looking because of the scroll if I made it multiline !

Comment: Try to increase number of rows

Comment: @test1604 increase rows of what ?

Comment: rows of textbox if you use it