# ASP.NET setting textbox value using javascript without document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have the following Web Form in my ASP.NET Website

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" ValidateRequest="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function SetTextBoxValues() {
                TextBox1.value = "Textbox can be set without calling document.getElementById()";
                TextBox2.value = "Textbox can be set without calling document.getElementById()";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="210px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="725px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br/>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="TextBox2" runat="server" />
    <br/>
    <button onclick="SetTextBoxValues()">Set Text Box Value</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The page works as I can click the button and set values in both TextBox1 and Textbox2. What I don't understand is the way the Textbox value is set in the javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetTextBoxValues() {
        TextBox1.value = "Textbox can be set without calling document.getElementById()";
        TextBox2.value = "Textbox can be set without calling document.getElementById()";
}
```

Normally we need to use the following JS code:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtTextBox.ClientID %>').value = "Some values";
```

But it looks like we can set the value without the use of document.getElementById(). May I know why it is working this way? Is this a valid way of setting textbox value using javascript?

Comment: I dont think this would be working

Comment: I created an empty ASP.NET website and added this page. I have tested it and was able to add text to the textboxes when clicking on the button.

Comment: It does work, indeed. I think the explanation is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quoting answer provided as comment from ConnorsFan.

> It does work, indeed. I think the explanation is given here:
>   [stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables). – ConnorsFan Jun 3 '16 at 12:29

Answer (score 0):

You use component "runat server" so you should use code behing:

```
TextBox2.Text = yourvalue;
```

And create a method server side to manage your inputs.

I think it's like this post:
[textarea control, asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508051/textarea-control-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: I know I should use code behind since it has the "runat server", but I want to know why javascript seems to be able to use code behind syntax in its function.

Comment: Two cases are possible : 1) ASP.NET create some global js variable you can access. 2) Your script is "runat server", why ? I don't know if I cannot see the whole code.

Comment: Thank you again for the response. I am not quite sure about what you mean my script is "runat sever". This is the whole code I have and there is no code behind for this web page. I created it by simplifying a web page from an old project of my company. There is no code behind in this page. All I did was add this web page to an empty ASP.NET website and it seems to be working.