# How to increase the text area in an input box in html/css?

Tags: html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbu1fbst/9/) in which I am trying to make the input box bigger.

I was able to make it bigger but for some reasons `the writing cursor starts from the middle of a box whereas I want it to start from the extreme top-left of the input box` so that I can write more content in it similar to [this](https://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_text_box_code.cfm).

The CSS which I am using to make the input box bigger is:

```
input 
{
    padding: 3px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

I am not sure what changes do I need to make in my HTML (in the fiddle) and CSS for the writing cursor to start from the extreme left in the input box.

Comment: For multi-line input, I suggest using [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) rather than [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple lines of input in <input type="text" />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262472/multiple-lines-of-input-in-input-type-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to get the text up by using the `padding-bottom` attribute

```
input 
{
  padding: 3px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

But what you probably want to use, instead of an `input` is a `textarea` just like in the example you mentioned if you want to have multiline text.

```
<textarea name="text" cols="25" rows="5">
Add multiple lines of text here and watch the scrollbars grow...
</textarea>
```

Comment: it worked. I am wondering what I have to put in asp. I am using the following code:
<div>
     
                    `<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocationDesc" runat="server" CssClass="tb-std"></asp:TextBox>
    
                </div>`

Instead of TextBox, I think I have to put something else but I am not sure what I have to put.

Comment: @david — I googled "asp tag textarea" and found [textarea control, asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4508102/17300) here on SO, which says to use `<asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" ... />`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just creating a `textarea`?
See the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ak9Ld3m1/)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem as you, and we fixed that using the tag `textarea` rather than using `input` tag.

My problem was solved.