# Does a Form tag for a ReportViewer needs an Action?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I'm using `VS2010` to create a simple aspx page with a `ReportViewer` control on it. The `ReportViewer` control loads a remote report from the server. That seems to work fine.

But when I fill in the textfields of the report, to filter on same data then nothing is shown...

I can clearly see that it is making a request through `FireBug`. But the request goes through `localhost`, but the reports are on a different server.

Doesn't that mean i have to specify a `URL` or something in the `form` tag? Both the `ReportViewer` and the `ScriptManager` are placed in a `form` tag with `runat="server"`.

So i'm not sure if i need to specify manually to what server to request has to be made for the `ReportViewer` to work properly.

Because all i see currently is the `textfields` of the report with which i can filter the data. But no report it shown, which normally appears underneath the `input` fields. The rest is just plain white.

Anyone any idea what i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The runat="server" is specifying if it should run on the server or the clients computer, it doesn't really have to do with the ReportViewer Control specifically, this is an ASP.NET thing.

See here: [runat="Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304290/why-does-asp-net-webforms-need-the-runat-server-attribute)

In order to get Reports to be fetched from a server you should look into Remote Mode,
See here: [Remote Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251669%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Hope this was enough to get you the results you need.

Comment: I've been trying to find the cause for days. Turns out there is something with the report... Other reports seem to be working fine, except the one i was given to test with. But i'll accept your answer anyway, since your answer is the current "best" answer.