# why to include runat="server" in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, runatserver

HI Guys
actually i was digging & quite confused from since i am working on `Web` with `ASP.NET`
THAT whenever i need to use a `server tag` (`control`) like
`<asp:Label ID="lblName" />`
& then to make it as a `programmable element`, so that i could access it in behind code i must
include `runat = "server"`                    but when if it must be included then how it will
differ from normal `HTML tag`, i mean what is the exact reason to include `runat = "server"` & 
whats the different between general `HTML` tag & an `ASP.NET` tag without `runat = "server"` ?

Comment: [Why does ASP.NET webforms need the Runat=“Server” attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/304290/why-does-asp-net-webforms-need-the-runat-server-attribute)

Comment: runat server means allt he Controls undergo Page Postback for Each Action

Answer (score 3):

When the markup code is parsed, everything is converted into server controls.

Any elements that are not tagged with `runat="server"` will just end up as a [`LiteralControl` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) with the HTML code as text.

For example, markup like this:

```
<div>
  <p>
    <span id="asdf" runat="server"> </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

will end up as the controls:

```
LiteralControl("<div><p>")
HtmlGenericControl("span") with id asdf
LiteralControl("</p></div>")
```