# X is missing a required attribute 'runat', but runat has one option only

Tags: asp.net, runat

I wonder, why do I have to include `runat="server"` to server elements in ASP.NET when `runat` only has one option and it is required for server elements. If not added it keeps telling me "missing a required attribute 'runat'".

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The `runat="server"` is there to let ASP.NET know which parts of your HTML is controlled server-side and which parts are not.

Please note that even standard HTML elements like `<table>` can have a `runat="server"`, which then exposes it to your code.

Comment: I understand that, but server controls MUST have it, then why add it? it should be by default and no need to keep nagging me about it. For HTML as it is optional, it makes sense..

Comment: Except all those server controls are entirely valid HTML. They may or may not be known element names, but how else do you expect ASP.NET to know? The `runat` directive is how ASP.NET can quickly and easily find all elements that it needs to parse/evaluate/replace.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a previous StackOverflow question that has input from some people at Microsoft as to why the `runat="server"` tag is explicitly necessary for server tags, while causing errors if omitted.

[Why does ASP.NET webforms need the Runat=“Server” attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304290/why-does-asp-net-webforms-need-the-runat-server-attribute)