# Problems with adding rows dynamically and save values in javascript and c#

Tags: c#, javascript

I created a table from my database and now I want to add rows and save it.
My problem is when I add a row for a second time, I do saved the row before in my database,
but this row gets as soon as the second blank row appears. If a refresh the page or using location.reload() first row is visible but not the second blank one.

I wrote in javascript (but my whole program runs in c#) :

```
function addRow() {
    var i = parseInt(document.getElementById('counter').value);
    if ((i-1)>=0) {
        var id = guid();
        save_row_before(i-1);
        var row = '<input ID="id'+ i + '" runat="server"type="text" 
        document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].innerHTML += row;

        document.getElementById('counter').value = i + 1;

    }
}

function save_row_before(i) {

    var r = document.getElementById('id' + i).value ;
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/saveRows",
        data: '{row: "' + r + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: if counter is ASP Textbox you need to add server tag "<%= Counter.ClientID %>"

Comment: var row = '<input ID="id'+ i + '" type="text"'; 
try this line

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Why does ASP.NET webforms need the Runat="Server" attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304290/why-does-asp-net-webforms-need-the-runat-server-attribute)

If you want an input to run on the server, you need to have it compiled before you deploy the app.

> > Keep in mind:
> >     Asp.net (c#) generates html.
> >     JavaScript manipulates that html.

If you add a row with runat=server:

```
var row = '<input ID="id'+ i + '" runat="server"type="text" ...
```

The codebehind will be unaware of that item.

Also note, typically you don't send html to the server.  Simply send json.

Here is a great tutorial using knockout.js:  http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving

Answer (score 0):

1st you must use ASP.net Server Names 
so counter textbox will call :

> getElementById('<%= counter.ClientID %>')

2nd point you can't add server side control use Javascript

> runat="server" have no mean here its client control