# C# NotSupportedException when adding InnerHTML into a HTML table

Tags: c#

In my `.aspx` file I have the `table` below:

```
 <table id="table1" style="width: 100%;" runat="server"></table>
```

I want to access this table and insert html into this table in `C#(.aspx.cs)`,I tried this:

```
 HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable)(form1.FindControl("table1"));
 table.InnerHtml = "<tr><td></td></tr>";
```

But I got `NotSupportedException`. How can I solve this?

Comment: Well, the documentation does indeed say you can't use InnerHtml: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.innerhtml(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you trying to add rows to the table? If so you should use HtmlTable.Rows.Add and the newly created row. Have a look here for some sample code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmltable.rows(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the control does not have a runat="server" your code behind will not be able to access the object at runtime. :)

Comment: Can you update the origional text? And perhaps show more of .aspx code.

Answer (score 3):

use runat server to make the table available serverside

```
<table runat="server" id="table1" style="width: 100%;"></table>
```

For reference you could take a look at this SO question - [Why does ASP.NET webforms need the Runat=“Server” attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304290/why-does-asp-net-webforms-need-the-runat-server-attribute?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to retrieve the table in the code-behind, you need to use a .Net control and declare your table using

```
<asp:Table runat="server" ... />
     ...
</table>
```