# How to clear value for html textbox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to clear the value of the html textbox in vb.net using the provided button by vb.net.

Can someone please help me?

The frontend code for html textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="Desc" id="desc" size="28" maxlength="50" value=''>
```

Button code:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
     desc.Text = "" 
     ' What code should I do here?
End Sub
```

Comment: add `runat="server"` to the HTML input, then you can access it by the ID and clear it with `desc.Clear()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access of HTML control in the back-End you have to give `runat="server"`. you can refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304290/why-does-asp-net-webforms-need-the-runat-server-attribute) for more information about `runat="server"`. Hence your input tag will be like the following:

```
  <input runat="server" type="text" name="Desc" id="desc" size="28" maxlength="50" value="sample">
```

There is no `Text` property for `HTML` controls, so you have to use

```
desc.Value =""
```

for Clear/Reset the value of the control

Answer (score 0):

I think `TextBox1.Text = ""` should be working, but try `TextBox1.Clear()` to clear the contents of the text box and allow re-entry. You also need to add `runat="server"` in your HTML input.

Comment: 'Text' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText'. so `TextBox1.Text = String.Empty` wont work