# Aspx get value from confirmed HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to get value from `label` with `id=lblValue`. On page confirm I see confirmed `HTML` as:

```
<span class="treeColorOrderBefPrepare">~
<div style='display:inline-block;'>
<img onclick='calculateDate.add(this);' style='cursor:pointer;' class="imageInBox" src="/_assets/images/icons/small/add.png"/>
<img onclick='calculateDate.subtract(this);' style='margin-left:3px;cursor:pointer;' class="imageInBox" src="/_assets/images/icons/small/subtract.png"/>
<label id='lblValue' style='position:relative;top:1px;width: 13px; height: 13px;margin-left:3px;margin-right:3px;'>0</label>
</div>&nbsp;
<img class="imageInBox" src="/_assets/images/icons/small/icon-small-merchandise.png"/>POPER ČRNI MLETI (0,0 KG) (fina. HKJ_TK, predp. Cent.predp: 04.04.2017 - 0,0 KG)</span>&nbsp;
<input type="text" name="DK_m_1_3_120000204_140000240-120003917-120000204-" value="">
```

All I need is to get value from `lblValue`. Is there a way to get this value? Values will range from -10 to 0. In the example above, value=0. I am doing this on the server side, not on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="javascript">
document.getElementById("lblValue").innerHTML
</script>
```

Comment: I would like to get this value on the server side.

Comment: add runat="server"

Answer (score 0):

Add *runat="server"* attribute like this:

```
<label id='lblValue' runat="server" style='position:relative;
top:1px;width: 13px; height: 13px; margin-left:3px;margin-right:3px;'>0</label>
```

and you will be able to use *lblValue* as a variable.

For more information, what runat attribute is doing, please see this: [Why does ASP.NET webforms need the Runat="Server" attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/304290/why-does-asp-net-webforms-need-the-runat-server-attribute)